# How to filter table after DAX UNION of other tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to filter table after UNION of other tables. How to reference new column name after SELECTCOLUMNS?

```
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tab1, "NewColor", Tab1[Color] ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tab2, "NewColor", Tab2[Color] )
)
```

How can we filter this table?

I tried this:

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    UNION (
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tab1, "NewColor", Tab1[Color] ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tab2, "NewColor", Tab2[Color] )
    ),
    [NewColor] = "Red"
)
```

But it raises error:

> Cannot find name '[NewColor]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Table =
FILTER (
    UNION (
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tab1, "NewColor", [Color] ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tab2, "NewColor", [Color] )
    ),
    [NewColor] = "Red"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to filter this table AFTER UNION, why not before?

You can do this in this way:

```
UNION(
FILTER(   
SELECTCOLUMNS('Tab1',"__dummy[color]",[Region])
,__dummy[color]="Red"),

FILTER(   
SELECTCOLUMNS('Tab2',"__dummy[color]",[Region])
,__dummy[color]="Green")
)
```

Comment: Because when we use AFTER then the code is simpler. Just one filter instead of multiple (could be a 100 :-)

Comment: Ok, but on other hand, you may do unnecessary CPU work, and allocate more memory than really needed :)

Comment: If they haven't optimized DAX mechanism for that yet, I am sure they will in the future. In the long run, the only thing we should really care about is the simplicity of code. I could advocate that in the short run it is also the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below option with Filter the source table first and then apply the UNION on filtered table-

```
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( FILTER(Tab1,Tab1[Color] = "Red"), "NewColor", Tab1[Color]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( FILTER(Tab1,Tab2[Color] = "Red"), "NewColor", Tab2[Color] )
)
```

**But** here is a big question, as you are filtering Tab1 and Tab2 and keeping only color **Red**, this will keep only one value **Red** in your destination table. Is that really meaningful? If so, you can just create a **Custom Table** with 1 value **Red**. Why some other steps like UNION should use?

Comment: It is just a clear example of the problem. My real need is that I want to exclude RED which very simple once you know the right answer. And doing it after simplifies code.